# Belongs_to too many columns ID

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many, belongs-to

I'm trying to create a Matches table. This matches table will look to get it's information from a Teams table. I'm having trouble getting the association to work.

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base  
#    
end

class Team < ActiveRecord::Base 

 belongs_to :matches, :class_name => "Match", :foreign_key => "hometeam_id"    
 belongs_to :matches, :class_name => "Match", :foreign_key => "awayteam_id"   

end
```

**My Match table has**

```
# id
# hometeam_id
# awayteam_id
# …
```

**My Team table has**

```
# id
# name
# …
```

**I want to be able to do the following**

```
game = Match.find(:first)
# <Match id: 1, hometeam_id: 64810937, awayteam_id: 78380562,
game.hometeam 
# returns "Toronto"
```

I'm not too sure if my belongs_to is the right way to do it. I feel like I'm repeating myself and their might be a better approach. Thoughts?

**UPDATE SOLVED**

```
class Match < ActiveRecord::Base

belongs_to :hometeam, :class_name => "Team"
belongs_to :awayteam, :class_name => "Team"

end


class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :homegames, :class_name => "Match", :foreign_key => "hometeam_id"
  has_many :awaygames, :class_name => "Match", :foreign_key => "awayteam_id"

end
```

Leaving this up for anyone else who runs into similar problems.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base 

 belongs_to :hometeam, :class_name => "Match", :foreign_key => "hometeam_id"    
 belongs_to :awayteam, :class_name => "Match", :foreign_key => "awayteam_id"   

end
```